# How to end a stream in node.js

Tags: node.js, stream

Im using this xml parsing module in my Node.js application https://github.com/assistunion/xml-stream. If a certain condition occurs, I would like to manually end the string instead of having it end when it reaches the end of the document. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code, you have not access to the underlying stream, unless you decide to use the _stream private property.

Anyway, it has a `pause` method. I guess you can freely stop it and discard the stream.

Comment: How do I discard it once its paused

Comment: Good question. I'm not sure (for I'm not an expert of the node's internals) that simply pause and ignore it will promote the stream for the GC. I'd rather remove all listeners, attach `function () {}` to the `data`, `end` and `error` signals and let the data pouring out even if ignored.